# Como criar Stored Procedures mysql com python a partir de aqruivos .sql

Tags: mysql, python, procedure

Tenho alguns arquivos **.sql** onde guardo uma **`procedure`** em cada arquivo.

- Um exemplo, **`procedure1.sql`**:

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS sp_teste$$

CREATE DEFINER=`db`@`%` PROCEDURE sp_teste ()
BEGIN

UPDATE tb_empresas SET emp_descricao = `TESTE` WHERE emp_codigo = 1;

END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Agora eu gostaria de criar um programa Python que lê cada um destes arquivos **.sql** e crie a **`procedure`**, caso ela não exista.

O programa atualmente consegue abrir e ler cada arquivo, sem problemas, mas, quando dou o comando **`cursor.execute(data)`**, recebo o erro:

> 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELIMITER $$
>   USE python_mysql$$
>   DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS sp_teste$$
>   CREATE DE' at line 1.

Eu não estou utilizando a função <kbd>**[`callproc`](https://pynative.com/python-mysql-execute-stored-procedure/)**</kbd>, pois não quero chamar **"executar"** a **`procedure`**, apenas cria-la, caso não exista.
Alguma dica?

Segue código que estou utilizando: (As procedures ficam em uma pasta chamada 'scripts', na raíz onde está o codigo python.

```
from tkinter import *
import os
#import MySQLdb
from mysql.connector import MySQLConnection, Error

window = Tk()
window.title("Instalador de Scripts")
window.geometry('350x200')

# Linha 1
lbl1 = Label(window, text="Servidor")
lbl1.grid(column=0, row=0)
txt1 = Entry(window,width=20)
txt1.grid(column=1, row=0)

# Linha 2
lbl2 = Label(window, text="Porta")
lbl2.grid(column=0, row=1)
txt2 = Entry(window,width=20)
txt2.grid(column=1, row=1)
txt2.insert(END, '3306')

# Linha 3
lbl3 = Label(window, text="Usuario")
lbl3.grid(column=0, row=2)
txt3 = Entry(window,width=20)
txt3.grid(column=1, row=2)

# Linha 4
lbl4 = Label(window, text="Senha")
lbl4.grid(column=0, row=3)
txt4 = Entry(window,width=20)
txt4.grid(column=1, row=3)


# Linha 5
lbl5 = Label(window, text="Banco")
lbl5.grid(column=0, row=4)
txt5 = Entry(window,width=20)
txt5.grid(column=1, row=4)
txt5.insert(END, 'conference')


def verifica():
    contador = 6
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk("./scripts"):  
        for filename in files:
            txt = Entry(window,width=20)
            txt.grid(column=1, row=contador)
            txt.insert(END, filename)
            contador = contador+1
            print(filename)


def roda():
    contador = 6
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk("./scripts"):  
        for filename in files:
            print(filename)
            filename = "./scripts/" + filename
            with open(filename, 'r') as file:
                data = file.read()
                print("Dados: " + str(data) + " FIM dos dados**********")

                con = MySQLConnection(
                    host="X",
                    user="Y",
                    passwd="Z",
                    database='W'
                )
                print(con)
                #con.select_db('conference_teste')
                cursor = con.cursor()

                try:
                    cursor.execute(data)
                except Exception as e:
                    print("Nao rolou o execute: " + str(e))


btn_verifica = Button(window, text="Verifica", command=verifica)
btn_verifica.grid(column=2, row=5)

btn_roda = Button(window, text="Roda", command=roda)
btn_roda.grid(column=3, row=5)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Opa Vinicius, insira como está seu código até o momento para que fique mais fácil de lhe ajudar.

Comment: Ajustado @AndréLins! Obrigado pelo feedback!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Descobri o que causava o erro.
A resposta está neste [LINK](https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL/issues/98).

Alterei meu codigo de:

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS sp_teste$$

CREATE DEFINER=`dbw`@`%` PROCEDURE sp_teste ()
BEGIN

UPDATE tb_empresas SET emp_descricao = `ATRI RP TESTE` WHERE emp_codigo = 1;

END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

para:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`dbw`@`%` PROCEDURE sp_teste ()
BEGIN

UPDATE tb_empresas SET emp_descricao = `ATRI RP TESTE` WHERE emp_codigo = 1;

END
```

Apenas retirei o DELIMITER e 'DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS sp_teste$$' do código.
A verificação se a procedure ja existe estou fazendo 'por fora':

```
# Busca todas as procedures existentes
cursor.execute('SHOW PROCEDURE STATUS')
procedures = cursor.fetchall()
# Para cada procedure que existe
for p in procedures:
    print(p[1])
```